# jQuery custom function with multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, function, object, parameters

I am trying to create a custom jquery function which has two parameters, the one a single string defining the method in which to update the second parameter; an object of selectors.

Here is an example of the usage of the function:

```
$.select_content("update", {
    "object_1",
    "object_2"
});
```

And the function:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    var methods             = {
        "update"            : function ( objects ) {
            $.each(objects, function (object){
                // Do stuff...
            });
        },
        "reset"             : function ( objects ) {
            $.each(objects, function (object){
                // Do stuff...
            });
        }
    };
    $.fn.select_content     = function ( method ) {

    };
})( jQuery );
```

However I get a return error in my console which exclaims a unexpected token `,` on the this line: `"object_1",",`.

Is there a better way to approach this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the json syntax require key value pair. You can try an array:

```
$.select_content("update", [
    "object_1",
    "object_2"
]);
```

But you can also use the selector syntax:

```
$.select_content("update", "object_1, object_2");
```

Then:

```
$(objects).each(function (object){
    // Do stuff...
});
```

Comment: +1 as you're right about the syntax error. Note, though, that it's not "JSON syntax".  It's "object literal" syntax. JSON is a data transport format involving serialized data structures *using* a subset of JavaScript literal syntax.

Comment: I completely forgot that objects required a pair and arrays didn't. Hehe, thanks :3

Answer (score 2):

While I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, your syntax error comes from this code sample:

```
$.select_content("update", {
    "object_1",
    "object_2"
});
```

In your second param, you are using object literal notation (`{}`, what some might mistakenly call JSON) without naming key/value pairs. That particular syntax error will go away if you use array literal notation instead:

```
$.select_content("update", [
    "object_1",
    "object_2"
]);
```

Or if you add key names:

```
$.select_content("update", {
    one: "object_1",
    two: "object_2"
});
```

Whichever of those changes you choose will fix the syntax error you're concerned about, as I said, but may not make the thing work. There are other issues in what you're showing us. A few are:

1. You show your function being defined on the jQuery prototype (`$.fn`), making it an instance object. However, you are calling it as if it were "static" via `$.yourFunc()`
2. You are defining your method on the jQuery prototype but you are not returning the collection against which it was run--which kills chaining.

Based on those two items, I suspect you meant to define you method under `$` as opposed to `$.fn`. But I cannot be sure of your intent.

Comment: How would I go about creating a static function with the two parameters I mentioned in my original post? Using it without the `$(content).myFunc()` and rather `$.myFunc()`?